# Best way in lxml to test if an element is the root

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am new to python and xml parsing, so this may be a very dumb question.  What is the best way to test if a given element if it is the root if the root is not known?  So for example, given a generic test.xml structure;

```
<root>
<child1>
<child2>
<child3>Some Text</child3>
```

And you have a function that takes in elements only.  The only way I have come up so far is something like this, but requires the root to be known to the function

```
 from lxml import etree as ET
 fulltree = ET.parse('test.xml')
 root = fulltree.getroot()

def do_stuff_with element (element):
       if (element is not root[0].getparent()): #Only works if root is known
       #do stuff as long as element is not the root
       else:
       #if we are at the root, then do nothing
       return
```

Originally I tried

```
      if (len(element.getparent()):  #return None if the parent
```

Since lxml treats elements similar to lists, I had expected it to return values for any children and None for the root that would not have a parent.  Instead for the root it returns an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have never used lxml before, but by looking up the documentation and thinking about it a bit: The root would be the only element that does not have a parent, correct?

```
from lxml import etree as ET
fulltree = ET.parse('test.xml')


def do_stuff_with_element(element):
    if element.getparent() is None:
        print("Element is root")
    else:
        print("Element is not root")


root = fulltree.getroot()
do_stuff_with_element(root)
do_stuff_with_element(root.getchildren()[0])
```

Comment: dang, it was a dumb question.  Yes that works.  I could have sworn that I tried some variant of this.  In any case.  Thanks.

Comment: I added what I had attempted originally to my question above just for future reference.